# How to compress png image without changing size

Tags: java

I need to compress png image but when I'm trying to do it I get a new png image with the bigger size. My code looks like the following:

```
public static BufferedImage compress(final BufferedImage originalImg, final int ratio, final String extension) {
        BufferedImage img = null;

        if (originalImg != null && ratio > 0) {
            final ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(extension).next();
            final ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            try {
                if (writeParam.canWriteCompressed()) {
                    writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
                    writeParam.setCompressionQuality(ratio / 100f);
                    final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    final ImageOutputStream outputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(output);
                    writer.setOutput(outputStream);
                    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(originalImg, null, null), writeParam);
                    output.close();
                    outputStream.close();

                    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
                    img = ImageIO.read(is);
                } else {
                    img = originalImg;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                writer.dispose();
            }
        }
        return img;
    }
```

I get this Image [image] it size is 49kb 
 but the result is 420kb [image]

What do I wrong?

Comment: You are not compressing a PNG, but converting a JPG to PNG. JPG is more suited for this sort of photo(-ish) image, with color gradients etc., thus is it smaller than the PNG, even when the latter is compressed.

Comment: @tobias_k I'm trying to compress ```png``` image but I couldn't upload it. Can you give me advice on how can I compress the png image? ```ImageIO``` library doesn't do it for me.

Comment: @John: PNG is a lossless format. It will never produce a small file size for these kinds of images (photo-ish, with color gradienst). It is best suited for simple line-art style images. JPEG is better suited for photo-ish pictures, but is lossy (i.e. it won't perfectly reproduce the original).